# Get value of hidden checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

I am able to get the value of checked checkbox by this query:

```
vals = $('input[name="checkedID"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

But, how can I get the value of **hidden** checked checkbox? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
vals = $('input:hidden[name="checkedID"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer on: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17382/form-checkbox-values-not-posting. I ended up using below script (with a few modification from the source):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var oTable = $('#idparent').dataTable();

        $('#form').submit(function () {
            $("input[name='checkedID[]:checked']").remove();
            $("input:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
                $('<input type="checkbox" id="checkedID" class="checkedID" name="checkedID[]" ' + 'value="' +
                  $(this).val() + '" type="hidden" checked="checked" />')
                    .css("display", "none")
                    .appendTo('#form');
            });
        });
    } );   
</script>
```

The value of checked checkbox need to re-append to the form on submit. Code above resulted in redundant value, so you need to remove the duplicate value after that.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter if the checkbox is hidden or not.

```
$('input:hidden[name="checkedID"]:checked').val();
```

with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkedID" value="Yes" style="display:none;" checked>
```

Returned what I expected. Here's a small fiddle of it: http://jsbin.com/kixujoci/2/

Keep in mind `:hidden` wouldn't work if the input isn't visible due to it being hidden by one of its **parents**.

Comment: Please provide your answer here rather than just a link to one.

Comment: @Bill Criswell: Thanks for the answer. That's what I mean in my question (sorry if it was unclear) >O< , the input isn't visible (not just hidden)

Comment: There would really be no elegant way to do that. The cleanest way I think would be working off a parent: `$('#list-of-hidden-checkboxes :checked');`

Comment: @Bill Criswell: I didn't catch what you mean, can you please elaborate a little more? `#list-of-hidden-checkboxes` is the ID of the parent (in this case is the table)?

Comment: @BillCriswell: Many thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. >O< , I have found the answer and post it. :)

Comment: It does answer your question. You just changed the question drastically based in the answer you provided though. Glad you got it working. This does not look right at all: input[name='checkedID[]:checked']